How to Prevent Overlap Between Absolute Positioned Bottom Section and Scrollable Content in Vue Dialog
I am working on a Vue application where I use a dialog (el-dialog from Element Plus) to display a form. The form has two main sections:
Scrollable content at the top (UnitConversion and other fields).
A bottom section (StockImageUpload, StockPricing, and StockDescription) that must always stay fixed at the bottom of the dialog.
I used position: absolute to keep the bottom section fixed at the bottom of the dialog. However, when the dialog size shrinks (e.g., due to a smaller screen or window resize), the bottom section overlaps with the scrollable content, hiding buttons and other fields.
Here is a simplified version of my components:
BaseDialog.vue component
<template>
  <el-dialog
    v-model="dialogVisible"
    :append-to-body="true"
  >
    <slot name="toolbar"></slot>
    <slot></slot>
  </el-dialog>
</template>


  <style lang="scss">
.base-dialog {
  max-width: none; 
  max-height: none;
  margin: 20px !important;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  overflow: hidden;

  :deep(.el-dialog__header) {
    background: $primary-color;
    margin: 0;
    padding: $spacing-unit * 2;

    .el-dialog__title {
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

  :deep(.el-dialog__body) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: $spacing-unit * 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
</style>

StockForm.vue component
<template>
<el-form class="stock-form">
<div class="unit-conversion-section">
  <UnitConversion :stock="form" />
</div>
<div class="bottom-section">
  <div class="image-section">
    <StockImageUpload />
  </div>
  <div class="pricing-section">
    <StockPricing />
  </div>
  <div class="description-section">
    <StockDescription />
  </div>
</div>

  <style scoped>
  .stock-form {
    margin-bottom: $spacing-unit * 3;
   

  .unit-conversion-section {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
  }

  .bottom-section {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
 }
}
</style>

UnitConversion.vue component
<template>
  <div class="unit-conversion">
    <!-- Conversion for Secondary -->
    <div class="conversion-row">
      <div class="conversion-section">
        <el-button
          class="var-ise-button"
          type="danger"
          @click="toggleSection('secondary')"
        >
          {{ t("stock.buttons.existSecond") }}
        </el-button>
        <div class="conversion-fields" v-show="showSections.secondary">
          <el-form-item :label="t('stock.labels.unit')">
            <el-select v-model="stock.secondaryUnit" class="w-100">
              <el-option label="PAKET" value="PAKET" />
              <el-option label="ADET" value="ADET" />
              <el-option label="GALON" value="GALON" />
            </el-select>
          </el-form-item>

...


<style lang="scss" scoped>
.unit-conversion {
  margin-top: 36px;
  gap: $spacing-unit;

  .conversion-row {
    display: flex;
    gap: $spacing-unit;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .conversion-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    height: 60px;
    .var-ise-button {
      max-width: 250px;
      min-width: 150px;
      min-height: 42px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-basis: 30%;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
  }
  .el-button {
    height: 40px;
  }

  .conversion-fields {
    display: flex;
    gap: $spacing-unit * 3;
    flex: 1;

    .el-form-item {
      flex: 1;
      white-space: nowrap;
      :deep(.el-form-item__label) {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    }
  }
  .w-100 {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
</style>

How can I ensure that the bottom section remains fixed at the bottom while the top section scrolls properly without being overlapped? Is there a way to dynamically adjust the layout or make the dialog scrollable in a way that accommodates both sections?
Any suggestions or guidance on CSS or JavaScript-based solutions would be appreciated

Hard to help on such a visual issue without proper visuals to help us out. Overall, I'd try to stay away from a position absolute if you want to be able to have more flexibility with it afterwards. Also, I would heavily recommend a CSS approach to solve such a problem, to which your browser devtools might help a lot. Regarding the problem itself, an easy approach like flexbox might be a good start with you flipping the order or just sticking it at the bottom if needed. CSS is plenty powerful nowadays.
